# Tried to hide navigation menu on one page ended up SCRAMBLING the navigation menu on another

Tags: menus, navigation

I am trying to remove the header and footer menus from this page (https://revrex.com/revrex-banking-onboarding) so that it is just blank with the embedded demo.

[image]

I got the Conditional Menus plugin to do so, followed the Internet's instructions to a tee, clicked save, and not only did it not work, but it scrambled the navigation menu for my About page (https://revrex.com/about).

[image]

1. How can I fix the navigation menu for the About page
2. How can I remove the navigation menu from the onboarding page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you okay with using CSS? It seems the plugin you installed has affected your header.
So I would uninstall the plugin and then with pure CSS, hide the header on the page you want to hide it.

So to hide it on the page you're mentioning, the CSS would be:

```
.page-id-3262 header {
  display: none;
}
```

You can insert the CSS in appearance -> Theme Editor, and then ensure you're in the style.css file, scroll to the bottom and insert it.